# Можно ли сделать, чтоб при нажатии на элемент класса, отображаемый на форме, вызывался метод как при нажатие на кнопку [Windows Forms (C#)]

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть сетка из объектов моего класса (всего 100 квадратов), и мне нужно, чтоб при нажатии на один из квадратов выполнялся метод, как при нажатие на кнопку. Можно ли это реализовать?

Код:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            g = this.CreateGraphics();
            Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3);
            g.DrawRectangle(redPen, 20, 20, 400, 400);

            Square[] square = new Square[100];
            Rectangle[] rect = new Rectangle[100];
            
            int X = 20;
            int Y = 380;
            for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            {

                square[i] = new Square(i, true, Image.FromFile(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Img\square.png"));
                rect[i] = new Rectangle(X, Y, 40, 40);
                g.DrawImage(square[i].NewImage, rect[i]);
                X = X + 40;
                if (X == 420)
                {
                    Y = Y - 40;
                    X = 20;
                }  
            }
        }
 public class Square
    {
        int id;
        bool cond;
        Image newImage;
        public Square(int id, bool cond, Image newImage)
        {
            this.id = id;
            this.cond = cond;
            this.newImage = newImage;
        }
        public Image NewImage
        {
            get { return this.newImage; }
            set { this.newImage = value; }
        }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Так как вы рисуете вручную, то и клики придётся обрабатывать вручную. В обработчике клика проверяете координаты мыши и высчитываете, в какую ячейку попали.

Comment: Не мучайтесь готовых контролов хватает, благо есть. Просто самому реализовывать так как вы делаете это длинная история. У вас следующим этапом появится события обработчики состояния и вы пройдете к своей кнопке или ещё какому нибудь Франкенштейну.

Comment: Примечание: рисовать нужно в событии `Paint`. В вашем способе, с использованием `CreateGraphics` рисунок будет стираться, например, при минимизации/показе формы.